# JSON data gets loaded but won't show in my app

Tags: java, android, json

At the moment I'm struggling with an Android application (Android Studio) that won't show my JSON data, but runs and loads it without problems. I'm controlling this by Logging out hardcoded text different places in my code. I have followed the tutorial by [Wingnity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Lr37suTPpg&list=PLsoBxH455yoZZeeza9TiG8I9dGP0zz5o9).

In my Actors.java class I have all the necessary getters and setters.

MyActivity.java (no missing import statements)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
    ActorsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();

        adapter = new ActorsAdapter(this, R.layout.row, actorsList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        ActorsAsyncTask aat = new ActorsAsyncTask();
        aat.execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

    }

    class ActorsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Double, ArrayList<Actors>> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Actors> doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<Actors> result = new ArrayList<Actors>();
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if(status == 200) {
                    Log.d("Status", status + "");
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("actors");
                    Log.d("Array", jsonArray.toString());

                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try{
                            Actors actor = new Actors();
                            JSONObject jsonRealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            actor.setName(jsonRealObject.getString("name"));
                            actor.setDescription(jsonRealObject.getString("description"));
                            actor.setDob(jsonRealObject.getString("dob"));
                            actor.setCountry(jsonRealObject.getString("country"));
                            actor.setHeight(jsonRealObject.getString("height"));
                            actor.setSpouse(jsonRealObject.getString("spouse"));
                            actor.setChildren(jsonRealObject.getString("children"));
                            actor.setImage(jsonRealObject.getString("image"));

                            result.add(actor);
                        } catch(Exception e){
                            continue;
                        }

                    }
                    return result;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Actors> result) {

            if(result != null) {
                actorsList = result;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ActorsAdapter.java

```
public class ActorsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Actors> ArrayListActors;
    int Resource;
    Activity context;

    public ActorsAdapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {

        ArrayListActors = objects;
        Resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(Resource, parent, false);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        TextView tv = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvD = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
        TextView tvDOB = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);
        TextView tvC = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
        TextView tvH = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
        TextView tvS = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpouse);
        TextView tvCh = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvChildren);

        //new DownloadImageTask(iv).execute(ArrayListActors.get(position).getImage());
        tv.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getName());
        tvD.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getDescription());
        tvDOB.setText("Birthday: " + ArrayListActors.get(position).getDob());
        tvC.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getCountry());
        tvH.setText("Height: " + ArrayListActors.get(position).getHeight());
        tvS.setText("Spouse: " + ArrayListActors.get(position).getSpouse());
        tvCh.setText("Children: " + ArrayListActors.get(position).getChildren());

        return rowView;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urlDisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dk.markflarup.jsongettime" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_my.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >

    <!-- A plain TextView for trouble shooting/
         Controlling my view at least will show content-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HEJ HEJ HEJ"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml (I have tried to remove all hardcoded text in my row.xml which resulted in no different outcome)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tom Cruise"
                android:textColor="#166CED"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#D64530"
                android:text="Date of Birth: July 3, 1962" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Height: 1.80 m"
                android:textColor="#D64530"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#D64530"
                android:text="United States" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#009A57"
        android:text="Description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSpouse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#166CED"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spouse: Katie Holmes" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChildren"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#166CED"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Children: Suri Cruise, Isabella Jane Cruise, Connor Cruise" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your `actorsList = result;` in the `doPostExecute`, try to do a debug and verify if the ArrayList has the data that you received just to confirm and exclude that problem.

Comment: Log.d("Result", result.toString()); gave me this: 7735-7735/dk.markflarup.jsongettime D/Result﹕ [dk.markflarup.jsongettime.Actors@420fbef8, dk.markflarup.jsongettime.Actors@420f19d8, dk.markflarup.jsongettime.Actors@420f1988, dk.markflarup.jsongettime.Actors@420ef960, dk.markflarup.jsongettime.Actors@420ee960, dk.markflarup.jsongettime.Actors@420ed748]

Comment: in order to get something useful from your logcat, you'll want to override `Actors.toString()` method to display actual names etc.

Comment: Try what Richard said in the answer below. This is what you need to do. `actorsList.clear();actorsList.addAll(result);adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update based on current adapter

You are returning a count of 0 in your adapter. This means that your adapter will display zero rows.

You should be returning the size of `ArrayListActors`. Rather change it to something like this:

```
public int getCount() {
    // wrong
    // return 0;

    return ArrayListActors.size();
}
```

Also your adapter is not returning any items from the data in your `getItem()` method. This means that once you fix the `getCount()` method, the adapter is still not querying your `ArrayListActors` for real data.

This should return the correct item from your `ArrayListActors`.

```
public Object getItem(int i) {
    // wrong
    // return null;

    return ArrayListActors.get(i);
}
```

---

### Original Answer showing how to assign data to an adapter

(I will leave this info here, as it may help future readers dealing with adapters.)
You need to set the new Actors list onto your `ArrayAdapter` before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Something like:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Actors> result) {
        if(result != null) {
            /* CHANGE IN NEXT LINE */
            adaptor.ArrayListActors = result;

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Setting the `result` onto your `actorslist` changes the object that `actorslist` is pointing at. This means that the reference inside your adapter no longer points to the new `actorslist`, but still to the old one.

So the display still shows the old data, which is what the adapter knows about.

---

Another alternative, as mentioned by Nightware in his comment, is to retain the same reference, but clear out and repopulate your `actorsList`.

This way the adapter is still referencing your same `actorsList` object, so when you change the contents of that object, the adapter is able to see the new information.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Actors> result) {
        if(result != null) {
            actorsList.clear();
            actorsList.addAll(result);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Depending on what you want to do with `actorsList` in other parts of your app, this may be a better approach. Personally I do not like to keep my data floating around outside the adapter once I've used it, which is why I would choose my first method, and not bother with the `actorsList` field.

Comment: It didn't bring me any other outcome. My screen is all white except the hardcoded text for controlling my view is able to show at least something.

Comment: Flark, try debugging the TextViews texts just before the `return rowView` inside your Adapter class. This should confirm to you whether your data is actually going to the ListView items or not.

Comment: @NightwareSystems, it doesn't show anything, which means you pointed me in the right direction! Thanks.

Comment: One thing I'd look at is this `JSONObject jsonRealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` Below that line just try this `jsonRealObject.toString(4);` and see the output, are you seeing the ACTUAL JSON values or just random numbers, that will confirm if you're getting the data in the right way or not.

Comment: That didn't seem to work either :( It won't print that specific object :/

Comment: @flarkmarup you can get similar results to what Nightware is suggesting, by following my earlier comment about adding `toString()` method to your `Actors` class. Then your logcat will output the data, or not. This will confirm what Nightware is trying to test i.e. if your list gets filled with real data.

Comment: @Richard, I think Android now already has a `toString()` for JSON by default as I tried it before I recall (It will print the result formatted with indentation and new lines and everything perfectly), check this post: http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-json-print-json-string-human-readable-format-debugging


@Flark, If done right, that should show you the actual values, name, count, ... etc. Better try to investigate the JSONArray too, can you actually confirm that the server side is passing the result to your app?

Comment: @NightwareSystems, this is the 'Log.d("Array", jsonArray.toString());' which responds with: 'D/Array﹕ [{"height":"1.80 m","spouse":"Jennifer Aniston","description":"William Bradley 'Brad' Pitt is an American actor and film producer. He has received a Golden Globe Award, a Screen Actors Guild Award, and three Academy Award nominations in acting categories","dob":"December 18, 1963","name":"Brad Pitt","image":"http:\/\/microblogging.wingnity.com\/JSONParsingTutorial\/brad.jpg","children":"Shiloh Nouvel Jolie-Pitt, Maddox Chivan Jolie-Pitt","country":"United States"} etc.'

Comment: Since we know the data is there, start narrowing down the possible error locations. I'd recommend this: Debug only the `first` object in the list at 1. arraylist befor calling NotifyDataSetChanged, 2. At the constructor of your Adapter class, 3. Before returning the rowView in the adapter (use position == 0 to get only first object). Using the `toString()` method, the 3 results should be identical with true values, the first one that doesn't match is the source of the problem. I went over your code and it seems pretty correct so must be a small thing we're missing.

Comment: Also, please try adding this in your `doPostExecute()` instead of the Notify call, maybe the notify is failing. `adapter = new ActorsAdapter(this, R.layout.row, actorsList);listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @flarkmarup have you been able to rule out the `getCount()` and `getItem()` errors in your code yet? Even if your adapter sees the data, you have told it to display zero rows of `null` data.

Comment: @Flark Please check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer was what you're missing, I created the project and found this to be the problem, please update those in your Adapter class:

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return ArrayListActors.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i)
{
    return ArrayListActors.get(i);
}
```

And this in your onPostExecute method:

```
if (result != null)
{
    actorsList.clear();
    actorsList.addAll(result);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And please mark Richard's answer as correct if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, @NightwareSystems! Really! I would like to upvote your answer, but because my reputation is that low ( rep < 15) I'm not allowed.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's all thanks to Richard for pointing it out from the start. Glad to be of help, good luck. :)